# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration' issue with dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration.tokenStore; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration.resource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5281) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration.tokenStore; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerTokenServicesConfiguration$JwtTokenServicesConfiguration.resource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This might be a dependency issue but I am unable to resolve it. Following are my dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapdb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.firebase</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>firebase-client-jvm</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>[2.5.2,)</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>com.firebase</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>firebase-token-generator</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>2.0.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev73-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.269</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
<version>${oauth.version}</version>
</dependency>
<properties>
        <oauth.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</oauth.version>
</properties>
```

I hope this might work.

Comment: It works, but why??